# Error with subscripted value being neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
    void display_grid(struct game_board *M, FILE *stream) {
        int i, j;

        /* malloc memory for appropriate amount of rows */
        M->border = malloc(sizeof(*M->border) * (M->width + 4));


        for (i = 0; i <= M->width; i+=2){
            M->border[i] = M->border[M->width + 1] = '+';
            for (j = 1; j <= M->width; j+=2){
                M->border[j] = M->border[M->width] = ' ';
                fprintf(stream, "%c\n", M->border[i][j]);
            }
        }
        M->border[M->width + 2] = '\0';

        fflush(stream);
   }
```

My question is in regards to this line `fprintf(stream, "%c\n", M->border[i][j]);` which shoots an error and stops the overall program from compiling.

At the moment I am simply trying to read in the height and width from what the user is providing from the command line and using that to print out a 2D grid that I can then use later on to modify and such.

I have a solution which I *THINK* might fix it but I have no idea on how to implement it. I believe that in order to fix the problem I need to malloc border as a ** and then malloc the rows as *

Comment: Wait... How many elements does `border` have? It looks as if you construct it with `width+4`, but try to read it as if it were `width(width+1)`.

Comment: Alright, I might've fixed something. I had originally declared border as a char * inside of a struct at the start of the program. In my understanding, this would in turn mean that I had declared a 1D array. But by changing the declaration of border to char **, I have now declared it as a 2D array. Would this be accurate?

Comment: You seem to have a misconception of how arrays work. The short answer is that *declaring a pointer* and *constructing an array* are very different things. The longer answer is that I urge you to play around with arrays in isolation (i.e. not as part of a structure or a complex project) until you can handle 1D or 2D (or higher) with ease, *then* incorporate them into other code.

Comment: `char **a` is **no** 2D array! Setup and usage is more complicated than using a proper 2D array. I agree with @Beta. You really should first learn to walk before starting to run.

Comment: what's the definition of struct game_board?

Comment: game_board, for me is defined as a struct that holds all the variables that I am currently using such as `int height`, `int width`, `int play_count`, `char **grid`, and `char **border`.

Comment: I now understand that by changing `char *border` to char **border, I actually only declared it or set it up to be used later as a pointer to a pointer. 
When going about actually using that char ** later on to construct/print out my 2D array though, I have it so that I iterate through every even `[i]` (including the 0th position) and print out a `+`. I then iterate through every odd `[j]` and print out a ' '

Comment: The end result I am hoping for is essentially something like this: 
`+ + + + +`
but now I've realised that in order to print the rows, I need to be implementing another loop that repeats for the height as well. I would definitely appreciate any corrections to my understanding.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, please post code that is small, shows the problem, and cleanly compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int **A;                        /* A points nowhere in particular */

A = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);   /* A points to the head of an array of int* */

A[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4); /* the first element of A points to an array of int */
A[1] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
A[2] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);

/* A can now be used as a 3x4 array */

A[2][3] = 99;
printf("%d\n", A[2][3]);

/* don't forget to tidy up */

free(A[0]);
free(A[1]);
free(A[2]);
free(A);
```

Don't attempt anything more complex until you have this working perfectly and understand it completely.